# Combinate animate.css with a jquery slider issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a simple layer slider with animate.css and basic jquery. The basic idea is when the next button clicked the next slide becomes visible, and the slide model gets the animated class. It is working for first, but when it cames to restart from the first slide, the animation stops working.

Here is the jquery:

```
$('.carousel-next').click(function(){
    $('.carousel-model').removeClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
    if($('.carousel-slide:last').hasClass('active')){
        $('.carousel-slide:last').removeClass('active');
        $('.carousel-slide:first').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.carousel-slide.active').removeClass('active').next('.carousel-slide').addClass('active');
    }
    $('.carousel-model').addClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
});
```

In the past few hours i tried countless methods to get it work properly without success, now i'm asking you if you may have that tricky key part what i missed :)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2c4C/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Really. Thanks for the notice, intresting. I'm working in firefox as always, because in 99% of the cases firefox renders well and chrome doesn't. Do you have any ideas about what could be the problem in ff?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that and awnsered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this animation guy called Daniel Eden screwed up his CSS on his website, which you are using.

**https://daneden.me/animate/animate.css**

He has forgotten all the `-moz-` prefixes.

Here is one:

```
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here this Jquery plugin

https://github.com/JohnnyBeGood34/JQuery-AnimateSlider

Hope help you